# How to create a MUC room from php or using direct command with ejabberd

Tags: php, ubuntu, xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I have an application which needs to register an **ejabberd user** when the normal registration process takes place. I handled this using the `ejabberdctl register` command.

Similarly, I need to add some users to an MUC group therefore, I need to create a group using php/command line.

I found the **ejabberdctl create_room** does what I need but I can't seem to make it work.

I used this:

```
sudo ejabberdctl create_room testRoom conference.localhost conference.localhost
```

But this prints out a stacktrace. **I have enabled mod_muc_admin**

[image: Stacktrace when using ejabberdctl create_room]

Now, the create_room command takes 3 arguments namely, **name**, **service** and **host**.

I can't seem to figure out this service parameter.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Have spent a whole day on this!

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and ejabberd 15.07

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters are described on [mod_muc_admin documentation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/ejabberdctl/muc-admin/#create-muc-room) page:

```
ejabberdctl create_room room_name muc_service xmpp_domain
```

Parameters are as follow:

- `room_name`: actual chat room name
- `muc_service_name`: usually "conference.YOURXMPPDOMAIN"
- `xmpp_domain`: The main domain of your service.

For example in your case, it should be:

```
bin/ejabberdctl create_room testRoom conference.localhost localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mickael, was stuck for a long time!
:)

Comment: I now want to add users(not invite) to a certain room I made, but I can't seem to find any command in the documentation or module for the same. Are you aware of something that can help?

Comment: You can change affiliations and there is a method for that on that module. However XMPP MUC protocol is presence based so to actually joing the room, the user need to send a presence to that room. It is needed because as it is designed, MUC rooms requires an active user session.